# Upgraded to 8.8.3 and now all of my modules say "No available releases found"

Tags: 8, updating

[image: Weird drupal 8 issue]

I just recently updated to 8.8.3 and for some reason, all of my modules now say "No available releases found". Also the one module I had that did report "No available releases found" (Video Embed for google drive), is now saying that that module is up to date. It is like they switched somehow when I updated. I might roll back but the site is currently working just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Press 'Check manually' in '../reports/updates/update', this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking "Check manually" once on the Available Updates page will resolve this issue.

Please see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3120168 for more info.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123819)

Comment: The question is literally "Any ideas?" so I'm not sure why this doesn't answer it. It's an idea. Further, it resolves the issue that the poster was experiencing. I've experienced the exact issue and this has been tested - it's not a flippant suggestion.

Comment: This answer provides a SOLUTION to the problem. However the code could be improved because the errors stem not from an actual problem but is instead a "Red Herring". The error message should probably provide some guidance?

Comment: Patching Drupal core is not the focus of a StackExchange answer. However, I've updated my answer with a link to the relevant issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem fixed itself. I am wondering if a cron job took care of it. I cleared cache and updated the DB, I just never thought to run cron.